# Slim Framework + Smarty Template Eng

Tags: php, smarty, slim

I have website on Smarty template engine and now added Slim Framework for routing, to change content in html i have assigned CONTENT to index.tpl

```
$template->assign(array('BASE' => $CONF['url.base'], 'THEME' => $SET['template'], 'CONTENT' => $CONTENT));
```

and i want to set $CONTENT value from route i have tried with this code but its not working:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($template, $CONTENT){
$CONTENT = $template->fetch('Route/home.tpl');
});
```

How i can do it?

My Smarty code is:

```
    /// INCLUDE SMARTY AND CONFIGURE
    require_once(CORE_DIR.'Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
    $template = new Smarty();
    $template->setTemplateDir(THEME_DIR.$WEBSITE['template']);
    $template->setCompileDir(THEME_DIR.'/templates_c/');
    $template->setCacheDir(CACHE_DIR);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use reference to pass `$CONTENT` variable and in addition you need to run your app before using `$CONTENT` variable so your code should look something like below:

```
$CONTENT = '';
$app->get('/', function () use ($template, &$CONTENT){
$CONTENT = $template->fetch('Route/home.tpl');
});
$app->run();
echo $CONTENT; // here you have modified $CONTENT variable
```

My whole testing code (in case you need it):

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();


$app = new \Slim\Slim(array (
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
)
);

$template = $app->view();
$template->parserDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/smarty';
$template->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$template->parserCacheDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';
$template->setTemplatesDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/smarty/templates');

$CONTENT = '';
$app->get('/', function () use ($template, &$CONTENT){
$CONTENT = $template->fetch('Route/home.tpl');

});

$app->run();
echo $CONTENT;
```

Comment: and where i need to register Smarty? (I have edited my codequestion and added there my smarty register code)

Comment: Look at my answer. Everything is in there